# Openlayers pointermove (hover) tooltip for multiple layers

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers-3

I've been able to display layer information on mouseover in Openlayers using the following:

```
//Style function for what happens upon hover
var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
    width: 3
  })
});


var info = document.getElementById('info');
var target = document.getElementById('map');

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (selected !== null) {
    selected.setStyle(undefined);
    selected = null;
  }
        if (evt.dragging) {
            info.style.display = 'none';
            return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        info.style.left = pixel[0] + 'px';
        info.style.top = (pixel[1] - 50) + 'px';
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
            selected = feature;
            selected.setStyle(highlightStyle);
        return feature;
    }, {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return layer.get('name') === 'layer_1_of_4';
        }
    });
        if (feature) {
            var rmk = feature.get('REMARK');
            info.style.display = 'none';
            info.innerHTML = 'Comments: '+rmk;
            info.style.display = 'block';
            target.style.cursor = "";
        } else {
            info.style.display = 'none';
            target.style.cursor = "";
        }
});
```

I tried making another `map.on('pointermove')` entry to select and display information from other layers on the map, but it seems only the first will fire. I have 4 layers I'd like to pull information from (all with different feature.get(NAME) entries, so I'd like to try and make it dynamic, perhaps only showing the information from the topmost layer or showing them all that match my layerFilter argument. Any ideas how to achieve this multiple layer pointermove issue? It doesn't seem like it should be that hard.

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel "To stop detection, callback functions can return a truthy value".  You `return feature;` which has a truthy value, so only the first is processed.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unsure of how this would be implemented. Can you provide an example and then I can try it out?

Comment: @Mike is there a way to perhaps not use the filter layer option since it returns a boolean value and instead use the for each layer at pixel function and run a series of if, else if, checks to see if it is a layer I should be displaying?

Comment: The forEachFeatureAtPixel callback passes the layer, it may be easier to use than a filter `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) { ... });`